# How to extend UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I m using UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource in 30 unity file, 
all with the same code, how I can make them reuseble extend them?
its just two methods of UITableViewDelegate and  some custom things like row height.

**Example:**

```
import UIKit
import MMDrawerController
import SwiftyJSON


class FooViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource  {
    var texto = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let load = Loader(view: self.view)
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        table.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0

        let api = API()
        api.get("agenda") { responseObject, error in

            let value = JSON(responseObject!)
            self.texto.append(value["agenda"]["textoagenda"].stringValue)

            self.table!.reloadData()
            load.stop(self.view)
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.texto.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.texto[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by extend? How to reuse code is one question. How to extend a table is another question. But "how I can make them reuseble extend " is mystifying as to what it means.

Comment: You can create a new Class as the dataSource of UITableView which hold an array of your data and implement the dataSource methods. But it does not called as extend the UITableView.

Comment: Its like put all code of table into one function/class

Comment: I assume you mean extend from a common base so you can get rid of duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller does not have to be the delegate. You can make any class the delegate.

```
class MyTableDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {

    // put table functions here

}
```

Then in your controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let load = Loader(view: self.view)
    table.delegate = MyTableDelegate()

    // etc

}
```

Of course, this means you have limited access to the properties of the controller.